# Is 'timeouting' a word?

Tags: grammar, word-request

When I write:

> The script is timeouting.

or:

> [Timeouting commands in shell scripts](https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/12/07/timeouting-commands-in-shell-scripts/)

The word *timeouting* is marked by Apple spell checker as non-existing.

Is it a valid word?

Comment: Caution: Spellcheckers mark plenty of valid words with red squiggly lines. Mine just underlined _Brexit_ and _qubit_, e.g. [This column](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2008/12/who_checks_the_spellcheckers.html) is almost 10 years old, but it's still an interesting read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not a word. The correct form is **"timing out"**.

The word **"timeout"** is a noun. For instance, this sentence is valid:

> You can call `set_timeout(10)` to set the timeout for the script to 10 seconds.

The verb form of this word is the [phrasal verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/phrasal-verbs) **"time out"**. The past tense form is **"timed out"** and the present continuous form is **"timing out"**. Example sentence:

> By default, the script will time out after 10 seconds. However, you can prevent it from timing out by calling the `disable_timeout()` function.

Regardless of tense, these phrasal verbs consisting of a verb plus a preposition are *always* written as two words separated by a space, while the noun and adjective forms are either written as a single word or use a hyphen separator instead of a space. Other examples from the world of IT include:

- **"log in"** is a verb, while "**login**" is a noun
- **"sign up"** is a verb, while "**signup**" is a noun
- **"set up"** is a verb, while "**setup**" is a noun

Some examples from outside the IT world:

- **"set back"** is a verb, while **"setback"** is a noun
- **"put down"** is a verb, while **"put-down"** is a noun

All of the above said, you probably shouldn't be shocked if you encounter an incorrect usage like *"timeouting"* in the real world. Mistakes involving separable verbs are very common in the world of IT, since there are a bunch of IT-related separable verbs in English and people who work in IT don't always have good English skills. The (widely used) `libcurl` library even used to have a `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED` constant before eventually renaming it to [`CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLEOPERATIONTIMEDOUT) (which is still a bit odd - it really ought to be `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMED_OUT`), so if you get this wrong, you're in good company.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any reference to either **timeout** or **time out** as a verb, but in my opinion the first sentence should be

> The script is timing out

For the second, the correct noun to use is **timeout** - see meaning 3 from the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time-out?q=timeout) - *Computing* A cancellation or cessation that automatically occurs when a predefined interval of time has passed without a certain event occurring.

> Timeout commands in shell scripts